# How to pass payment gateway parmament to an api in json in django

Tags: json, django, django-forms

How do i get Collect data with the parameters below and send as a json payload to an api in djnago    .  https://test.theteller.net/checkout/initiate

merchant_id
transaction_id
desc
amount
redirect_url
email
API_Key
apiuser

Comment: use post method of requests module